# Limit of a series (Gamma distribution)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

How does one calculate 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^k}{k!}?$$
Numerically it is somewhat close to $\frac12$. But to prove that I am going around a circle! Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: Taylor series of $e^x$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$